# Why my loop code have different behaviour i++, ++i , i+1

Tags: javascript

Here how it should work

```js
const myArr =[6,8,10,5];
function weSort(arr){
  let done = false;
  while(!done){
    done = true;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
        done = false;
        [arr[i],arr[i+1]] = [arr[i+1],arr[i]]
      }
    }
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(weSort(myArr))
```

But if i change the **i+1 to i++** it doesn't do anything because i++ is also 0.
i++ is post increment which means it will increment right after it done executing **(CMIIW)**

```js
const myArr =[6,8,10,5];
function weSort(arr){
  let done = false;
  while(!done){
    done = true;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(arr[i]>arr[i++]){
        done = false;
        [arr[i],arr[i++]] = [arr[i++],arr[i]]
      }
    }
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(weSort(myArr))
```

But if i change the i++ to ++i shouldn't it work like the i+1 since ++i is pre-increment which will add first before got put inside [i]. So shouldn't it look like this? 
`let i = 0`
`arr[i]>arr[++i] === arr[0]>arr[1]`

Like this code below (Note This Code cause `infinite` loop)

```
const myArr =[6,8,10,5];
function weSort(arr){
  let done = false;
  while(!done){
    done = true;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(arr[i]>arr[++i]){
        done = false;
        [arr[i],arr[++i]] = [arr[++i],arr[i]]
      }
    }
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(weSort(myArr))
```

Why it works differently than the first code snippet with `i+1`?
and cause loop

if something not clear feel free to comment to ask for further info.
I'm sorry for the bad grammar English is not my native i try to explain the best i could.
Thank you.

Comment: The difference is that with `++i` or `i++` you are _modifying_ `i` every time, so you are now increasing it several times in the same iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i + 1` will do the calculation and return the result, leaving `i` untouched

`i++` will return the value of `i`, then increment i (do `i = i + 1`)

`++i` will increment `i` (`i = i + 1`), then return its value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#arithmetic_operators

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that both `i++` and `++i` and are self assigning. Both the expressions modify the value of the variable `i`.

In your first snippet, the `i + 1` does not modify the value of `i` - but only generates a new value by adding 1 to the current value of `i`.

No modification to the loop variable is done there - therefore the loop is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

`i++` (or `++i`) should only be written one time. That increments the value. only do that once.

I think you want to avoid: `arr[i]>arr[++i]`

because now you are additionally incrementing `i` every time that check happens, which logically doesn't really make sense.